# error during importing project from another laptop in android studio

Tags: java, android

this project was in completely working state but when i import in my android studio, its getting errors on built. I am posting error image here please help me to solve this problem. here is the error.

```html
Error:Execution failed for task ':poondiAppSdk:processDebugResources'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\StuDy\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

[image]

Comment: if possible share your gradle build

Comment: @prabhat yadav  check the gradle file

Comment: Change the appcompat version in your build.gradle file back to 22.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Post your build.gradle file for more clarification... Try to compile project with SDK 23

Answer (score 0):

here is gradle

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.poondi.poondiapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':poondiAppSdk')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile files('libs/picasso.jar')
}
```

Comment: try lowering your compile build and targert value to 21. and Change the appcompat version in your build.gradle file back to 22.2.1

Comment: I used your idea but this problem occure

Comment: com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task '
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\StuDy\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'




}
```